# How to get a last element of an oversized array?

Tags: c, arrays

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int capacity = 5;
  int used = 0;
  int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * capacity);

  printf("Insert numbers one by one, send -999 to break input flow: \n");
  for (;;)
  {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num == -999)
    {
      break;
    }

    if (used == capacity)
    {
      capacity *= 2;
      arr = (int *)realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * capacity);
    }

    arr[used] = num;
    used++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Imagine, that "used" variable is unknown and so is "capacity".
You get an array of an unknown length.
How would you get last "useful" element of the array?

Comment: The "real" size is 30. If you want the size to be as the size of initializer, then do `int array[] = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4};`

Comment: Do you mean the number of elements in the array explicitly populated by you by the "real size"?

Comment: Imagine it's a dynamic array. Memory, allocated for it, is larger, than size of its contents.

Comment: You can get the size by definining the initializer in a macro and then using a compound literal within sizeof. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This is not a dynamic array, it is static. And so it's size. The fact that you are not initializing some elements *explicitly* doesn't mean they are not there (And yes, they are initialized *implicitly* to zeros).

Comment: If the last "real" element is guaranteed to be non-zero, then "Yes", otherwise "No". The reason is that any elements that aren't specified in the initializer are set to 0. So given that the last "real" element is non-zero, you can search from the end of the array to find that element. Note this only applies to a static array with an initializer. If you allocate the array using `malloc`, then only the elements of the array that you explicitly initialize will have values that you can depend on.

Comment: The edited version of the question has nothing in common with the original.

Comment: There is no `array` variable in the new code, so `sizeof(array)` needs to be fixed. And even if you fix the name, that sentence is still false. That calculation does not work for arrays that are allocated with `malloc`, nor with arrays that are function arguments.

Comment: *Capacity can be get using sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)* - Nope. There is no Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a Javascript style encapsulated array functionality.  You will have to make your own in C.  Check out this link, describes in detail...
https://www.happybearsoftware.com/implementing-a-dynamic-array

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in standard C tracks any distinction between the values of elements set by default initialization versus the values set explicitly by the program, and nothing in standard C tracks which elements have been set explicitly by the program. The only way for a program to detect the last element of an array that it has assigned a value is to maintain whatever information is necessary for that.

One way to do that is to remember the index of the last element that has been assigned a value.

Another way to do that is to initialize all elements of the array to a value that is not used for any other purpose. Then the contents of the array can be examined to see what the last element without that marker value is.

There are other ways, but all involve the program maintaining its own information. C does not provide any such service.